# PDO - Dynamic bindParam - value of 0 strange result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So thanks to suggestions from users here I have started porting my code over to PDO.  Everything was going well until one little issue.

I have a small function to handle my database calls, which basically generates the SQL query, does the $dbh->prepare ($sql), then loops through and binds the values, then executes the query.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ($sql);
// bind parameters
if ($action == 'insert' || $action == 'update') {
    reset ($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if ($value != 'NOW()') {
            $sth->bindParam (':' . $key, $value);
        }
    }
}
$sth->execute();
```

This works fine until I need to insert a value of '0'.  No errors are returned, but the value that is inserted into the db turns out to be the maximum value for the column type in the table, in this case is "137".

I'd prefer if someone could explain what is happening as well as providing a solution rather than just give me a fix so I can better understand this.

Cheers,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding the parameters correctly, check out [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).
You should use:

```
$sth->bindParam (':' . $value, [PARAM TYPE - example: PDO::PARAM_INT]);
```

Comment: Ahhhh.  Yes.  Would it be safe to detect this type on the fly? Something like: `if (is_int ($value)) { .. } else if (is_float ($value)) { ... }` etc.. ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your implementation, you can detect it dynamically, but I would rather "know" in advance (when the parameter is created to also create a "type" and pass it as well). If you decide to detect it dynamically, don't forget that `==` is useless, use `===` in case of `0` and there are functions like `is_double` (for every type) which you can use as well.

Comment: one more thing, even though that [*this article*](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) complains about PHP "bad behavior" I actually found it good & interesting, you can learn a lot about PHP from reading it!

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the process of writing INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements with a function that I simply pass some parameters to, including an array with $key => $value pairs which represent the column name and its value.  With mysql_* it worked beautifully, however this is proving to be a bit more complex.  Perhaps I need to OO it.

Comment: It's a good thing that you stopped using [mysql_*](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). PDO is much safer and if you re-use prepared-statement it also has a good effect on performance. Like I said, when you pass the column-name and value - you can also pass the column type, that would be my preference. And you're most welcome!