# write data to DB with PDO give strange result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code for connecting PDO:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = DataBase', 'kkk', 'kkkkkk');
if ( $conn ) { echo 'Connect Shodee'; }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $e->error();    
}
```

and this lines for INSERT the values:

```
function InsertFileToDb($filename, $filetype, $recieve, $update, $from, $comment, $file) {
$sql="INSERT INTO `DataBase`.`assistance`(`filename`,`filetype`,`recieve`,`update`,`from`,`comment`,`file`) VALUES(:filename, :filetype, :recieve, :update, :from, :comment, :file)";
$prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $prepare->execute(array(
                    ':filename'=>$filename, ':filetype'=>$filetype, ':recieve'=>$recieve,
                    ':update'=>$update, ':from'=>$from, ':comment'=>$comment, ':file'=>$file));
```

but when I fetch the data from my DB, some values like `$from` that is in UTF-8 encoding become just like `0o_xd7sjnc,x`...
would you tell me what is wrong?
I checked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947362/strange-pdo-behaviour) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568181/pdo-dynamic-bindparam-value-of-0-strange-result) and some other posts bt didn't find the right answer...

Comment: You need to check the form that you send. Can you echo $from before inserting into db and see what is the result.

Comment: I checked and this is OK...

Comment: check your database field types - are all strings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe it's an encoding problem, so you could try these steps and see what happens:

Add this: $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Database;**charset=utf8**','kkk', 'kkkkkk');

Make sure that your database tables are `utf8_unicode_ci`

Also add this to your html page in the `<head>` tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score -1):

Neither PDO nor mysql ever alter your data.
So, it's rather were altered somewhere else.

By the way, you can write your function less toilsome way

```
function InsertFileToDb($filename, $filetype, $recieve, $update, $from, $comment, $file) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO assistance VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $conn->prepare($sql)->execute(func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: thank you, I figured it up, I have set my collation with this:
 $PDO -> exec("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_persian_ci';");
 $PDO -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
 $PDO -> exec("set names utf8");
Thanks every body